# How can i find specific new object of Class that has a constructor argument equal to input

Tags: javascript, class, methods, constructor

I have a class called Country with 4 constructor parameters.

I then create some new countries from that class with specified values.

My question is, how can i create a method that can find and return the object with a this.value equal to the input in the method?

```
class Country {

  constructor(name, area, population, topdomain) {
    this.name = name;
    this.area = area;
    this.population = population;
    this.topdomain = topdomain;
  }

  static findCountry = domain => {
    /*Here is where the magic should happen. 
      If domain is in any of the countries below, then it should return the country name.
     */
  }
}

norway = new Country("Norway", 323802, 5320045, ".no");
sweden = new Country("Sweden", 450295, 9960487, ".se");
russia = new Country("Russia", 17098242, 142257519, ".ru");
china = new Country("China", 9596960, 1379302771, ".cn");
```

This function here should return "Norway":

```
Country.findCountry(".no");
```

Comment: why did you cut out the findCountry method? What have you tried so far? I dont think you are really understanding how classes work here. You should be calling your method on an instance of your class ie. norway.findCountry('.no') which obviously doesnt make sense because you already know the country.

Comment: I cut it out because i really didn't come anything near what i wanted... Also i agree that it makes no sense to make a function like this, but i was looking at some earlier exams in my course, and one of the questions was to create a function like this

Comment: The function makes sense but using it on a Class like you are doesnt. Think of Country like a template it doesn have anything in it. When you say norway = new Country()  norway is now an instance of your Class. You want to "do things" with the instance not the Class itself.

Comment: Yes i completely agree, but the last question on the exam was literally: 
"Create a method that takes a domain name as an argument and returns which country it belongs to,
based on the information we have stored in our objects."

Answer (score 0):

For that to work, the class has to keep a list of all the created instances. As JS has no weak references, this will mean that none of the instances can ever be garbage collected (so be careful):

```
 static instances = [];

 constructor(/*...*/) {
   /*...*/
   Country.instances.push(this);
 }

 static findCountry = domain => {
  return this.instances.find(country => country.domain === domain);
 }
```

Comment: Which versions of JS do you need to use to have static properties?

Comment: Okay, I assumed the `static findCountry = domain` was simply an error.

Comment: tbh i really do not know what i am doing. I went into a deep rabbit hole and this post was just a cry for help lol

Answer (score 0):

Don't come here to ask people to write your code ;)

```
class Country {
    constructor(name, area, population, topdomain) {
        this.name = name;
        this.area = area;
        this.population = population;
        this.topdomain = topdomain;
        Country._ALL.push(this);
    }
    static findBy(key, value) {
        let output = [];
        for ( let i in Country._ALL) {
            let c = Country._ALL[i];
            if (c.hasOwnProperty(key) && c[key] === value)
                output.push(c);
        }
        return output;
    }
}
Country._ALL = [];
```

**WARNING!** ES6 classes do not support static variables like `static variable = [];`
If you want static class variables in ES6 you have to use `ClassName.variable = [];` **after** the class declaration.

Comment: "Don't come here to ask people to write your code ;)" is a bit contradicting to the fact that you answered the question. If you think the question is not appropriate don't answer ... if you answer focus on the answer itself.

Comment: Look at the emoticon. It was not 100% serious. Also i thought it was important to warn that there are no static class properties in ES6 like shown in your answere.

Answer (score 0):

Your class doesn't know about the 4 objects you instantiated somewhere. You need to put them in a collection (e.g. an array), and then explicitly reference that collection in your search method:

```
class Country {
  constructor(name, area, population, topdomain) {
    this.name = name;
    this.area = area;
    this.population = population;
    this.topdomain = topdomain;
  }

  static findCountry(domain) {
    return (knownCountries.find(country => country.topdomain == domain) || {}).name;
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  }
}

const norway = new Country("Norway", 323802, 5320045, ".no");
const sweden = new Country("Sweden", 450295, 9960487, ".se");
const russia = new Country("Russia", 17098242, 142257519, ".ru");
const china = new Country("China", 9596960, 1379302771, ".cn");

const knownCountries = [norway, sweden, russia, china];
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```